# Mouse scroll is jumpy in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mouse, google-chrome, window, scrolling

I am having a problem with my USB mouse in Ubuntu 16.04. The scrolling is very jumpy in any window that I working in (be it a native application, or in the chrome webbrowser). I know that some issues with chrome web browsing flickering have been reported, and I don't know if this is related to my mouse issue. But otherwise this jumpy mouse scrolling is driving me nuts! Its like the scroll will work for a few clicks down, then suddenly, it jumps back up! Is this a driver issue or a bug in the kernel, and are there any workarounds that I can use in the meantime while waiting for the issue to be fixed?

Are there are any Ubuntu 16.04 users out there facing the same problem? Does anyone know if a fix is coming soon? Help!